# NullPointerException at android.app.activitythread

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-logcat

I'm trying to get the images in a grid view using universal image loader. But once I made this code the log started giving some error saying

```
04-03 21:45:12.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1271): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
04-03 21:45:12.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1271): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader/com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader.ImageGridActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-03 21:45:12.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1271):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1647)
04-03 21:45:12.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1271):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
04-03 21:45:12.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1271):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
04-03 21:45:12.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1271):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
04-03 21:45:12.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1271):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
04-03 21:45:12.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1271):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
04-03 21:45:12.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1271):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
04-03 21:45:12.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1271):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-03 21:45:12.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1271):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-03 21:45:12.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1271):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
04-03 21:45:12.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1271):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
04-03 21:45:12.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1271):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
04-03 21:45:12.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1271): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-03 21:45:12.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1271):     at com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader.ImageGridActivity$ImageAdapter.getCount(ImageGridActivity.java:78)
04-03 21:45:12.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1271):     at android.widget.GridView.setAdapter(GridView.java:131)
04-03 21:45:12.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1271):     at com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader.ImageGridActivity.onCreate(ImageGridActivity.java:59)
04-03 21:45:12.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1271):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
04-03 21:45:12.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1271):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1611)
```

Here the code goes like this
Constants.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.util.Log;

//import com.example.parseimage.JSONParser;

public final class Constants {

    public static String url = "http://ensign119.com/assets/image11.php";

    public static String[] IMAGES;

    protected static final String TAG_PRODUCTS = "image_path";
    protected static final String TAG_CID = "file_id";
    public static final String TAG_NAME = "file_name";

    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> mylist = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
    JSONParser jParser = new JSONParser();
    JSONArray products = null;

    private Constants() {
        JSONObject json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(url);

        Log.d("path_parsing", "before parsing");
        try {
            // Getting Array of Contacts
            products = json.getJSONArray(TAG_PRODUCTS);

            // looping through All Contacts
            for(int i = products.length()-1; i >=0; i--){
                JSONObject c = products.getJSONObject(i);

                // Storing each json item in variable
                String cid = c.getString(TAG_CID).toString();
                String name = c.getString(TAG_NAME);
                // creating new HashMap
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

                // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
                map.put(TAG_CID, cid);
                map.put(TAG_NAME, name);

                // adding HashList to ArrayList
                mylist.add(map);
                Log.d("mylist_value", mylist.toString());
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        Log.d("path_parsing", "after parsing");   

        IMAGES = new String[mylist.size()];
        for(int i=0; i<mylist.size(); i++){
           IMAGES[i] = mylist.get(i).get("file_name");
        }
        for(String path: IMAGES){
            Log.d("path", path.toString());
        }
    }

    public static class Config {
        public static final boolean DEVELOPER_MODE = false;
    }

    public static class Extra {
        public static final String IMAGES = "com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader.IMAGES";
        public static final String IMAGE_POSITION = "com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader.IMAGE_POSITION";
    }


}
```

imageGridActivity.java

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.GridView;
import android.widget.ImageView;

import com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader.Constants.Extra;
import com.nostra13.universalimageloader.core.DisplayImageOptions;

public class ImageGridActivity extends AbsListViewBaseActivity {

    String[] imageUrls;

    DisplayImageOptions options;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.ac_image_grid);

        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();
        imageUrls = bundle.getStringArray(Extra.IMAGES);

        options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
            .showStubImage(R.drawable.ic_stub)
            .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.ic_empty)
            .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.ic_error)
            .cacheInMemory()
            .cacheOnDisc()
            .bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
            .build();

        listView = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gridview);
        ((GridView) listView).setAdapter(new ImageAdapter());
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                startImagePagerActivity(position);
            }
        });
    }

    private void startImagePagerActivity(int position) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImagePagerActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra(Extra.IMAGES, imageUrls);
        intent.putExtra(Extra.IMAGE_POSITION, position);
        startActivity(intent);
    }

    public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return imageUrls.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                imageView = (ImageView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_grid_image, parent, false);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[position], imageView, options);

            return imageView;
        }
    }
}
```

Please help me on this. I'm a newbie to android.

Comment: please post the full stacktrace

Comment: where is your activity?

Comment: `imageUrls` seems to have been initialized. How do you put image urls when you create the `ImageGridActivity`?

Comment: @LazyNinja: I edited the content. Please check it.

Comment: @PCoder, `imageUrls` has been given a value, but that doesn't necessarily mean it's not `null`, as `bundle.getStringArray(Extra.IMAGES);` could be `null`

Comment: @MattTaylor, I seem to have missed a _NOT_ making my comment completely useless :(!

Answer (score 0):

I guess that your problem derived from this line:

```
imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[position], imageView, options);
```

verify that `imageView`, `imageUrls at position` (position) and the `options` object are not `NULL`.

Answer (score 0):

This line in the stacktrace:

```
04-03 21:45:12.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1271): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
04-03 21:45:12.653: E/AndroidRuntime(1271):     at com.nostra13.example.universalimageloader.ImageGridActivity$ImageAdapter.getCount(ImageGridActivity.java:78)
```

Suggests that your `getCount` method is returning null, which would then indicate that `imageUrls` is null, as then `imageUrls.length` would be null as well, giving you the `NullPointerException`.

Another problem is what you've done here:

```
@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}
```

As then when Android tries to retrieve your views, you're giving it null, which will also result in a `NullPointerException` at some point. If you're not sure what you're doing, don't override methods. If you're *forced* to override methods, make sure you know exactly what the OS needs. Just because you don't use `getItem()` in your own code, doesn't mean that Android doesn't use it.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your `imageUrls[]` array is not empty or null, I think your problem is at `getItem( int position )`. Try changing as below.

```
 public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return imageUrls.length;
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return imageUrls.get(i); // change here like this
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ImageView imageView;
            if (convertView == null) {
                imageView = (ImageView) getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.item_grid_image, parent, false);
            } else {
                imageView = (ImageView) convertView;
            }

            imageLoader.displayImage(imageUrls[position], imageView, options);

            return imageView;
        }
    }
}
```